# Storing details from one table into another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add items to my basket table in the database when the add button is clicked. here is my form with the button:

```
<div id="products-container">
            <?php
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=','name','password');
                $result = $pdo->query('SELECT file_id, productName, price, stock FROM files');
                foreach($result as $row){
                    echo "<form method='post' action='addbasket.php' id='shop'>";
                    echo "<img id='product' src=\"mfile.php?id={$row['file_id']}\">";
                    echo '<p>' . $row['productName'] . '</p>';
                    echo '<p>' . "£" . $row['price'] . '</p>';
                    echo '<p>' . "Stock Level: " . $row['stock'] . '</p>';
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">';
                    echo "</form>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

I then have a separate file with my php for adding the items to that table, so what im trying to do is store the session name, fileid, productname and price in the basket table (the fileid, productname and price are from the files table in the database) at the moment it just redirects to a blank addbasket.php page and doesnt add anything to the database. can anyone see where i've gone wrong?:

```
<?php

function newAccount(){
    $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', 'name', 'password');

    $name=$_SESSION['userName'];
    $fileid=$_GET['file_id'];
    $productname=$_GET['productName'];
    $price=$_GET['price'];


$st = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO basket (Username,file_id,productName,price) VALUES (:userName,:file_id,:productName,:price)');
    if(!isset($error)){
        //no error
        $sthandler = $pdo->prepare("SELECT file_id FROM files WHERE file_id = :file_id");
        $sthandler->bindParam(':file_id', $fileid);
        $sthandler->execute();

if($sthandler->rowCount() > 0){
    die(header("Location: mproducts.php"));

}else {

$st->execute(array('Username' => $name, 'file_id'=>$fileid, 'productName'=>$productname, 'price'=> $price));
    header("Location: mproducts.php");

    }
    }


if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    newAccount();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: the first step to debugging this would be to add echo statements so you can see the queries that are created.  That will easily tell you if there's a problem in the query

Comment: Be sure to print your SQL statements to help for debugging as @MarshallTigerus said. But from a quick glance it looks like your `'userName'` value is bound incorrectly. At one point it is `'userName'` and another it is `'Username'`

Comment: Look at your form first, 1) You used `post` method but you're catching the values using `$_GET` superglobal. 2) Neither there's any `<input .../>` fields with *file_id*, *productName* or *price*, nor you appended these values in the `action` attribute. 3) *...it just redirects to a blank addbasket.php* means something is broken. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP scripts and see if it yields any error or not.